# Is it possible to "disable" the period key in a HTML number field using an Android soft keyboard on an Android Web View html5 app?

Tags: android, html, android-softkeyboard, jquery-events, keycode

When I check the keyCodes on the softKeyboard for <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>  , the `e.key` in JavaScript is "Unidentified" and the `e.keyCode` is 229 for all of those characters.

The device I am using is a TC52k scanner and the scan trigger has the same key and keyCode... so it can't be completely disabled.

I don't know how many things I tried that didn't work... but I will post some...

This is a dynamic field bound with rivets.js using JSON objects

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".qty-input", function(e) {
    let code = e.keyCode;
    if (code == 229 && $(this).val().charAt(str.length - 1) == ".") {
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));
    }
});
```

^Basically, that says that if the last character has the code 229 and the last character of the entered string is a '.', then cut the last character off... but doesn't work correctly.

I also did this that basically says to only accept keys that have keycodes between 48 and 57 which are keys 1-9 on the android soft keyboard.

```
<input class="qty-input" placeholder="0" type="number" min="0" step="1" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 && event.keyCode != 229" pattern="[0-9]*" autofocus>
```

Also didn't work...

Does anyone have experience with this and can help?
I know there's lots of unsolved posts about this online.
It's the last thing I have to do and its keeping my app from being deployed!

Also... I've tried these function using events: keyup, keydown, change, input and keypress...

Comment: Have you tried... pattern="\d*" or  pattern="[0-9]*"? 

Example: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">

Can't test right now otherwise I would try to prove/disprove.

Comment: I have tried that... Works in the browser but not Android Chrome

Comment: This is the best solution that I have found so far:

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best workaround that I found (since 229 also triggers the 'scanner' trigger, I have to detect whether a string includes a barcode and a quantity and will have to separate the two(the keyCode for a `[.]` again is the same as the keyCode for the scanner trigger)) 
The 2 conditions determine 2 things:

If the value is longer than 3, then it is not allowed as a quantity because the quantity can not be over '500', so when it has a length longer than 5, it is considered to be a barcode.

```
let oldVal = '';
let newVal = '';
let barcode = '';
$(document).on("keydown", "input.received-qty", function(e) {
    let code = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode;
    oldVal = $(this).val();
});

$(document).on("keyup", "input.received-qty", function(e) {
    let code = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode;
    newVal = $(this).val();
    if (code == 229 && e.target.value.length >= 3) {
        barcode = $(this).val().slice(oldVal.length - 1, -1);
        $(this).val(oldVal);
    } else if (code == 229 && e.target.value.length <= 3) {
        let x = oldVal.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "");
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).val(x);
    }
    console.log("oldVal : ", "[", oldVal, "]", "newVal : ", "[", $(this).val(), "]");
});
```

This is the best way I've tried so far.

Comment: What do you see in keypress?  $('input.received-qty').keypress(function(event){

Do you see the "." if you set a breakpoint? I don't have access to your emulator so it's hard to help specifically, but if you could catch the keypress and figure out's a unallowable value with regex.test() and then just use "event.preventDefault" it may end up a little cleaner.

Comment: I know, and its very hard to explain because its so specific. e.key is "Unidentified", e.code is just "", and e.keyCode is 229. e.preventDefault doesn't work in this case. Almost as if an event with keyCode 229 is not even registered.